# How to use Ember query parameters with beforeModel and select?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

Demo: http://jsbin.com/zexopa/1/edit?html,js,output

I use the query parameters in my application. And the `queryParameters` are `'name'` and `'category'`.

The `'name'` parameter is used in the select and the `'category'` uses the input, but there is something wrong with the select `'name'` if I set it default to null.

If I change the `'name'`, the `'name'` always is undefined in the url.

Route:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  beforeModel: function() {
    this.controllerFor('index').set('products', [1,2,3]);
  },
  model: function() {
    return [{'is_active':false, 'name':'One'}, {'is_active':false, 'name':'Two'}, {'is_active':false, 'name':'Three'}, {'is_active':false, 'name':'Four'},{'is_active':false, 'name':'Five'}];
  },
  actions: {
    queryParamsDidChange: function() {
      this.refresh();
    }
  }
});
```

Controller:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  queryParams: ['name', 'category'],
  name: null,
  category: null
});
```

Template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  <h2>Welcome to Ember.js</h2>

  {{outlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  {{view "select" content=products value=name prompt="all"}}
  {{input type="text" value=category class="form-control"}}
  <ul>
    {{#each model as |item|}}
      <li>{{item.name}}</li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</script>
```

Can you help to check what happens to my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query params must be string to be properly binded. Your input works, as the value is `String` object. In `name` array you provided `Integer`. Unfortunately, I have not found any mention about that in docs, but you can see a working demo here: http://jsbin.com/lixili/1/edit?html,js,output

If I can give you some tip about your code:

- `beforeModel` is not a place for setting controller properties, do it in `setupController` method as in JSBin provided
- You did not defined query params in route, but you could and get rid of the `queryParamsDidChange`

Hope I helped!

Comment: Thanks. My `products` comes from my server, so I use `beforeModel` here. And the data like `[{id: 1, name: 'name'}, {id: 2, name: 'name2'}]`, if I want to available the select I must make the `id` to `String`?

Comment: If you have access to API you can do it. But in some scenario it may be impossible. Than you can use computed property to format your data from server and use it as input for `queryParams`. I wrote an example for you in that JSBin - http://jsbin.com/lixili/2/edit?html,js,console,output